# Apache Phoenix - sqlline.py vs sqlline-think.py - what is the difference?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, apache-phoenix

Apache Phoenix - `sqlline.py` vs `sqlline-think.py`.

Both are executable scripts which get you to the SQL-like CLI.

What is the difference between the two?
Is it a significant one or...?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it the purpose of the THIN client in the documentation: https://phoenix.apache.org/server.html

---

> Phoenix 4.4 introduces a stand-alone server that exposes Phoenix to “thin” clients. It is based on the Avatica component of Apache Calcite.
>
> Phoenix provides two mechanisms for interacting with the query server. A JDBC driver is provided in the standalone phoenix--thin-client.jar. The script bin/sqlline-thin.py is available for the command line.